# How to organize log files from Jenkins builds?

Tags: logging, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, archiving

Currently I have a Jenkins job with console output that I would like to save to separate log files. I already know how to create the log files with UNIX commands, but I'm trying to figure out the best way to organize these files. **Does Jenkins provide any sort of "universal" build number?** I could use the $BUILD_NUMBER and $BUILD_TAG-$BUILD_ID, though I figured a hash or some other sort of label would be more durable. (What happens if past builds get deleted?)

I could also label the log files based on the timestamp the Jenkins build was kicked off, but I'm unsure of how accurate it would be. **Does Jenkins record a "master time" for when a build starts/ends?**

Other suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as well. How do you store your Jenkins log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $BUILD_TAG should be good enough, it's usually like "Jenkins-$JOB_NAME-$BUILD_NUMBER", of course you could append the UNIX timestamp to make it more unique, so it would become something like Jenkins-$JOB_NAME-$BUILD_NUMBER-1234567890.

To answer your 2 questions specifically :

1. **Does Jenkins provide any sort of "universal" build number?**

   It is incremental automatically (still increase even if you delete the past builds) unless you reset it, so it could be regarded as universal in my opinion.
2. **Does Jenkins record a "master time" for when a build starts/ends?**

   Jenkins records the build start time, you can find it in the build history.